# Why are ls and locate returning different file names?

Tags: linux

We have recently deployed a commit that took a file called `MyfileController.php` and changed it to `MyFileController.php`

If I navigate to the file's directory and call `ls` or `nano MyFileController.php` it finds the file as `MyFileController.php`

If I run `locate MyFile` it is not found.

If I run `locate Myfile` it is found as `MyfileController.php`.

Unfortunately it appears that our framework cannot find the correct file `MyFileController.php`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you updated the locate database? `sudo updatedb`

Answer (score 2):

Nathan has the correct answer. updatedb usually runs once a day as a cron job, so it hasn't caught up with today's changes. But its very fast, just run it anytime if you suspect its out of sync.